# scope.$watch not called in directive when unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

## Problem

I am testing a directive.  The directive has a watch on a scope variable, but the watch is never called.  Putting the `$watch` call directly inside the unit test works.  Why isn't the `$watch` in the directive not called?

Thanks!

## Details

Here's my original test.  The directive has a watch in it, looking at `'reEvalCreateDate'`.  It's never called and the date string is always empty.

#### Test with no watch statement in it

```
it('should inject a date string', function()
    {


        scope.reEvalCreateDate = reEvalCreateDateAsNumber;

        expect(elm.text()).toBe('');

        scope.$digest();

        expect(elm.text()).toBe(new Date(reEvalCreateDateAsNumber).toUTCString());


    });
```

As a test, I put the watch within the unit test.  It is correctly called and the test passes.

#### Source (modified to put the watch in the test itself)

```
it('should inject a date string', function()
    {

        scope.$watch('reEvalCreateDate', function(newValue, oldValue)
        {
            var date = new Date(newValue);
            scope.dateString = date.toUTCString();

            dump(scope.dateString)
        });

        scope.reEvalCreateDate = reEvalCreateDateAsNumber;

        expect(elm.text()).toBe('');

        scope.$digest();

        expect(elm.text()).toBe(new Date(reEvalCreateDateAsNumber).toUTCString()); //This passes!


    });
```

#### Directive Source Code

Here's the directive code with the watch statement in it.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
            {
                scope.$watch('show',function(shouldShow){

                    console.log('should show reeval timer? ' + shouldShow);
                    if(shouldShow) {
                        $(element).fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                    else if(shouldShow === false){
                        $(element).fadeOut('slow');
                    }

                });

//this statement's never called when testing!!
                scope.$watch('reEvalCreateDate', function(newValue, oldValue)
                {
                    var date = new Date(newValue);
                    scope.dateString = date.toUTCString();
                });

            }
```

#### Setup Code

Here's all the init code for the test.

```
var elm, scope;

var reEvalCreateDateAsNumber = 1359487598000;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile)
{
    // we might move this tpl into an html file as well...
    elm = angular.element(
        '<reeval-timer show="showTimePopup" re-eval-create-date="reEvalCreateDate" class="re-eval-timer" ng-cloak >' +
            '{{dateString}}' +
            '</reeval-timer>');

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));
```

### Update

Per the comment, I don't think that I am setting the scope on the directive; I don't see anything on the API that allows me to do that.  I've tried several permutations of the `$compile` call, attempting to set the scope on it:

*create an element from html, pass it to compile.  No luck.*

```
elm = angular.element(
  '<div>' +
    '<tabs>' +
      '<pane title="First Tab">' +
        'first content is {{first}}' +
      '</pane>' +
      '<pane title="Second Tab">' +
        'second content is {{second}}' +
      '</pane>' +
    '</tabs>' +
  '</div>');

scope = $rootScope;
$compile(elm)(scope);
```

*and by creating an element first*

```
var element = $compile('<p>{{total}}</p>')(scope);
```

If the issue is that I'm just not setting the scope on the directive, the error would likely be in my `beforeEach`, I think.  Here it is:

```
describe('Reeval Timer', function()
{
    var elm, scope,element;

    var reEvalCreateDateAsNumber = 1359487598000;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile)
    {
        // we might move this tpl into an html file as well...
        elm = angular.element(
            '<reeval-timer show="showTimePopup" re-eval-create-date="reEvalCreateDate" class="re-eval-timer" ng-cloak >' +
                '</reeval-timer>');

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

....
```

Comment: Does your directive create an isolate scope? When you edit `scope.reEvalCreateDatae` are you setting it on the directive scope or the parent scope?

Comment: Andy, yes, it does create its own scope. I think that would make a lot of sense that I wasn't setting the scope properly.  I've updated the post with my initialization code.  How would one set the scope on the element itself?

Comment: Try `var directiveScope = element.children().scope();`

Comment: No luck, `var childScope = elm.children().scope();` returns 'undefined' and I get an exception when attempting to set an item on the undefined variable.

Comment: it might return undefined if you are looking on childScope before the $digest. element = $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
        scope.$digest(); // <-- after this scope should have children

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar issue while testing a directive with isolate scope.

The reason it wasn't called is that `$digest` "processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children" (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope).  Now, you would think that a directive's bi-directionally bound variables (defined with "=") would be watching the test's scope, but I found that my `$watch` wasn't being called.  Is this a bug in angular?

My solution was to wrap all the testing code after the `scope.$digest()` into a `$timeout`, e.g:

```
inject(function($timeout) {
  // change test scope variable
  scope.$digest();
  $timeout(function() {
    // assertions
    expect(...)
  }, 0);
}
```

Edit: Also see [Unit testing an AngularJS directive that watches an an attribute with isolate scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979282/unit-testing-an-angularjs-directive-that-watches-an-an-attribute-with-isolate-sc)

Comment: This likely just skips the actual assertions, if you add a `console.log` in there, more likely than not you won't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing what seems like the same problem. In my case, my directive had a `templateUrl` set rather than a hardcoded `template`, so in my unit test I also had to set up a mocked http request by calling:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/template.html').respond('<div></div>');
```

Everything else looked the same as your example, and my watch wasn't being called.

Then I remembered when using `$httpBackend` for mocking the request, you have to call `$httpBackend.flush()` like so:

```
$compile(elem)(scope);
$httpBackend.flush();
```

As soon as the flush call was hit, my watch was called.

Hope this helps....

Jason

Comment: I'll give `flush()` a go.  thanks for the input, Jason.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Btw, to solve your problem, you might consider replacing your expectGET with $httpBackend.whenGET('/template.html').passThrough();
I recommend reading up on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178804/testing-directives-that-uses-templates